# Press and Long press

Tags: actionscript-3

Okay I read tons of posts about this but I couldn't find good enough answer.
So I have this in my constructor class:

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mousedown);
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseup)
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, showInfo);
```

And I have these 3 functions:

```
    private function mouseup(e:MouseEvent):void {
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseup);
        myTimer.reset();
    }
    private function showInfo(event:MouseEvent):void{
        //long press code
    }
    private function mousedown(event:MouseEvent):void{
        myTimer.start();
    }
```

On usual click it does what its supposed to but when it comes to long click (1.5 sec) it echoes this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.events::TimerEvent@2ff0bab1 to flash.events.MouseEvent.
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

Another thing..On normal click there should be one action and on long click another action.
My code does both actions on long click. Any advices on how could I make it not run first action on long press?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event type should be TimerEvent, not MouseEvent

```
private function showInfo(event:TimerEvent):void{
    //long press code
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed my error problem,all left now is how to disable first action on long press :S

Comment: Solved it,sorry for bothering. :)

Comment: @Morsus If Pan correctly answered your question, you should mark it as correct to close the question out and reward Pan with reputation (select the outlined checkmark under the down arrow on the left side)